# How to apply transformations to line equation?

Tags: coordinate-systems

I use line equation of style $y=a*x +b$ , I want to apply transformations (rotation, translation in $x$ and $y$) on the line without changing the form by only changing the $a$ and $b$, I know for translation in why I would just add the the RHS, how to perform the rest of the operations?

Comment: Fix $b=0$ and try some different values for $a$. See what you get. The general idea is: translate the line so that $b=0$, rotate it, and translate back to where you want it to be.

Answer (score 3):

- **Translation** by $h$ units **up**: $y=ax+b+h$
- **Translation** by $h$ units **to the right**: $y=a(x-h)+b$
- **Rotation** by $\theta$ radian counterclockwise, around the origin: not as easy... Write $x=u\cos\theta+v\sin\theta$ and $y= -u\sin\theta +v\cos\theta$. Plug this into original equation: 
  $$ -u\sin\theta +v\cos\theta=au\cos\theta+av\sin\theta+b \tag1$$ 
  Simplify: 
  $$ v = \frac{(a\cos\theta+\sin\theta)u +b }{\cos\theta-a\sin\theta}   \tag2$$ 
  You can put $x,y$ instead of $u,v$ in (2), and arrange the terms as $y=Ax+B$ if you like. But if  $\cos\theta-a\sin\theta=0$, the rotated line is vertical, with equation $(a\cos\theta+\sin\theta)u +b$. You can't write it in slope-intercept form.

Comment: Can the whole transform in 3D be expressed by a homogeneous transform matrix?

Comment: If you put the line in standard (ABC) form matrix transformation gets the angle right but not the translation.  The C comes out wrong.  Can't figure it out.